# Coding a response to a button press event rather than a change event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, events

I hope this can be understood.  I’ve been working on this for about two weeks now and I’m just digging a bigger hole.

The following (fairly standard code) refills a selection option object (id=brand) from a mysql query , the parameter for which is the value of ‘brand’, called in ‘fetch.php’  when one of the previous options is selected:

```
$('#brand').change(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch.php',
        'brand='+$('#brand').val(),
        function(result){
            $('#brand').empty();
            $.each(result.result, function(){
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+this['brand']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    );
});
```

However, I also want to have a button on index.html that will also do the same thing except, rather than use the value of ‘brand’ as the parameter of the query, I want to use the value of a text object (id=demo) on the webpage.

My problem is how to construct the code above to call ‘fetch.php’, after the click of a button, and using the value of demo, so that the selection object ‘brand’ will be rebuilt.

Comment: How is this a php question? There is none for what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The most immediate solution would be to clone the existing code and make the needed modifications to it (listen on button click, use the value of the other field).

```
$('#brand').change(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch.php',
        'brand='+$('#brand').val(),
        function(result){
            $('#brand').empty();
            $.each(result.result, function(){
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+this['brand']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    );
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch.php',
        'brand='+$('#demo').val(),
        function(result){
            $('#brand').empty();
            $.each(result.result, function(){
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+this['brand']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Instead, you could extract the common part of the two code blocks to make it reusable:

```
// The common part.
function fetchBrands(brand) {
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch.php',
        'brand='+brand,
        function(result){
            $('#brand').empty();
            $.each(result.result, function(){
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+this['brand']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    );
}

// Listen for change event on the select element.
$('#brand').change(function(){
    fetchBrands($('#brand').val());
});

// Listen for click event on the button.
$('#button').click(function(){
    fetchBrands($('#demo').val());
});
```

Comment: amazingly quick response.  I'll try that now.

Comment: I'm working on this second option extracting the common part of the two code blocks, except to test it I'm only using the 'Listen for change event on the select element'  but I'm not getting an update of the select object now.  I've inserted a 'document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML = 'GOT HERE' just after the $('#button') line; to see if the code is getting there but it isn't.  Is there a bracket missing or something?  I think something isn't right with those 3 lines of listen for change event....

Comment: It was the semi colon after 'brand='+brand rather than the comma! Working well now!

Comment: fetchBrands($('#demo').val());  is seen as ‘undeclared’. The ‘demo object’ is declared in index.html as:  <p id="demo">books</p>   I am assuming that  fetchBrands($('#demo').val());  is OK for a select option but not for a string type object. I've tried,  
fetchBrands($('# document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML’);  with every combination with/without hash,speechmarks.  I have tried first putting the content of demo into a variable and then passing the variable as a parameter but nothing seems to work.  Does anyone know how to pass the content of a text object as a function parameter.

Comment: Used a var in the end:   
var temp = cat[cat.length - 1];
fetchBrands(temp);   That worked after two weeks!!  Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: The `.val()` method only works for inputs (and other form elements), hence you cannot get the contents of a `<p>` tag with it. For `<p id="demo">books</p>` you should use the `.text()` or `.html()` methods: `$('#demo').text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.triggerHandler( eventType [, extraParameters ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) and use `extraParameters` (they are explained in the [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) documentation).
They will get passed as parameters to the registered event handlers for that event.

> The `event` object is always passed as the first parameter to an event
> handler. An array of arguments can also be passed to the `.trigger()`
> call, and these parameters will be passed along to the handler as well
> following the `event` object. As of jQuery 1.6.2, single string or
> numeric argument can be passed without being wrapped in an array.
>
> Note the difference between the extra parameters passed here and the
> `eventData` parameter to the `.on()` method. Both are mechanisms for
> passing information to an event handler, but the `extraParameters`
> argument to `.trigger()` allows information to be determined at the time
> the event is triggered, while the `eventData` argument to `.on()` requires
> the information to be already computed at the time the handler is
> bound.

Modify the signature of your `change` event handler to:

```
function(ev, brand) {
  // ...
}
```

Use the `brand` parameter in your change handler if it is available or the selected value of the dropdown otherwise:

```
brand = brand || $('#brand').val();
```

Then use this for the `.getJSON()` call:

```
$.getJSON(
  'fetch.php',
  'brand=' + encodeURIComponent(brand),
  ...)
```

You can then trigger the event handler with any brand you want (e.g. `$("#demo").text()`) with:

```
$("#brand").triggerHandler("change", $("#demo").text())
```

An working example (with a fake `getJSON()` method)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#brand').change(function(ev, brand){
    brand = brand || $('#brand').val();

    getJSON(brand, function(result){
      $('#brand').empty()
                .append("<option></option>");

      $.each(result, function(){
        $('#brand').append('<option>'+this['brand']+'</option>');
      });
    });
  });

  // the "reset to default values" button
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#brand").triggerHandler("change", $("#demo").text());
  });
  
  // initially fill the drop-down (I didn't want to write the default options also in the markup...)
  $("#brand").triggerHandler("change", $("#demo").text());
});


function getJSON(brand, callback) {
  const fakeResponse = {
    A: [ { brand: "AA" }, { brand: "AB" } ],
    B: [ { brand: "BA" }, { brand: "BB" } ],
    default: [ { brand: "A" }, { brand: "B" } ]
  }
  
  callback(fakeResponse[brand]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">default</div>
<select id="brand"></select>
<button>Reset to "default"</button>
```

Comment: If it takes me a while to respond to all this please bear with me - there's a lot to take in.  Some great ideas.